# How to fix wordpress impreza theme page error?

Tags: html, wordpress, menu, navigation, wordpress-theming

Hi I am using wordpress impreza theme. I have got 5 pages. When I am logged on to wordpress pages are opening from the menu bar. but when I am clicking on menus for different pages pages not loading, returns back to home page but permalink changes. I would appreciate if anyone can help me in this. My site address: https://iimexpo.co.uk/

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You have a one-pager, with different sections. Your links need to point to the IDs of those sections, as you are doing it (seemingly) correctly with the "pricing" section, using an *anchor*  after the homepage URL, like `https://iimexpo.co.uk#solutions` for the "solutions" section and similar for the others.

But for this you also need to assign the IDs (as HTML attributes) to those sections, which are missing.

Comment: Dear @Johannes Thank you so much for your message. Well, pricing is only anchored from home page but for other nav menus, I got separate pages, i.e. [iimexpo.co.uk/about][1], [iimexpo.co.uk/solutions][2]. same I have got for "career" & "contact us". So when I am logged on to wordpress dashboard they are working. When I click on those menu or visiting pages links are opening. But only doesn't work when I'm signout from wordpress. I would really appreciate if you can help me to navigate and fix it. Sorry, I am amateur
  [1]: https://iimexpo.co.uk/about
  [2]: https://iimexpo.co.uk/solutions